# How to use slicing in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am finding slicing in Python a bit very difficult. Lets say if I want the first five and last five characters of a phrase to display how do i go about it. For example:

```
words = input("Enter a word ")
slice = words[:2]
print(slice)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative indexing for slice from end :

```
>>> s="teststring"
>>> 
>>> s[-5:]
'tring'
>>> s[:5]
'tests'
```

Actually a slice notation observes the following law :

```
[start:end:step]
```

> One way to remember how slices work is to think of the indices as pointing between characters, with the left edge of the first character numbered 0. Then the right edge of the last character of a string of n characters has index n, for example:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
-6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Read more about slicing https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

And https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Comment: thank you but how can I add both the [-5] and [ :5] in one rather than two separates. Thank you

Comment: @paapame You can not do it just with slicing but you can remove the string from index `x` to `-x` with replacing it with empty string `''`. `>>> s.replace(s[3:-3],'')
'tesing'
`

Comment: @Thank you for your help, you have been very helpful to me

Comment: you are awesome look at this:                                                                Enter a word IamGoing TotheSuperMarket
IamGo
arket